# Getting sqlite to work in ASP.NET 5 (vnext)

Tags: asp.net, sqlite, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I'm trying to get "EntityFramework.**SQLite**": "7.0.0-beta1" to work within ASP.NET 5.

I've created my project using Yeoman and installed EF sqlite from the package manager.

**The project builds fine but when running I get:**

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Logging.ILogger, 
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'or one of its
>   dependencies.

**My project.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.SQLite": "7.0.0-beta1"
},
```

I'm suspecting a versioning issue here

**Things I've tried :**

Tried using beta5 for EF only to have other packages breaking. I've also changed "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5" to the latest and got to the point where the db created successfully but then broke when it got to services.AddMvc();

**I've checked the sample project into git hub:**
https://github.com/roboriaan/asp567

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for beta 6, that includes proper SQLite support and samples. Beta 6 comes tomorrow! (July 27)

Comment: Thanks Erik. Good idea.

Comment: Beta5 packages were just released, you'll have to wait a bit for beta6 release.

Comment: You can use the dev bits if you don't want to wait :)

Comment: I'm also giving that a shot Victor.

Comment: This ended up working beautifully. Really appreciate the help guys. Upgraded to beta6. And as Pinpoint mentioned, just lookout for that "UseSqlite" not "UseSQLite" ext method. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an Example https://github.com/Schr3da/ASP.net-vnext-samples project which modifies the asp.net Mvc sample to work with Sqlite

https://github.com/Schr3da/ASP.net-vnext-samples

regards
Schreda

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix beta1 and beta5 packages. Given that the SQLite provider is still a work in progress, your best option is to use the latest beta7 nightly version, that fixes a few bugs. Make sure to also update your DNX runtime using `dnvm upgrade -u`

You can find the latest package on MyGet: http://myget.org/gallery/aspnetvnext

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've upgraded to beta7 but see the extension method for `optionsBuilder.UseSQLite` is not there anymore. That's probably being worked on? I'll keep on searching.

Comment: It's still there, but it's named `UseSqlite`, not `UseSQLite` (different casing): https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Sqlite/SqliteDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions.cs#L14. `AddSqlite` is still there too: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Sqlite/SqliteEntityFrameworkServicesBuilderExtensions.cs#L21

Comment: I'm only getting UseModel. Will recheck. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you're correctly importing the `Microsoft.Data.Entity` namespace.

Comment: Just to make 100% sure. All my packages needs to be the same beta#. So if I go sql beta7 all my other packages must go to beta7?

Comment: Yes, latest beta6 packages might work with early beta7, but that's definitely not a guarantee, specially since massive naming changes have been added to DNX.

Comment: Shweet! Will keep that in mind. Will add to git as I make progress.

Answer (score 0):

Now that beta 6 is out, checkout the [Getting Started with ASP.NET 5](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet5.html) guide. This uses SQL Server. The [Getting Started with OS X](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/osx.html) guide uses SQLite.