# SQLite reference in ASP.NET 5 WebApp

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core

App version - ASP.NET 5 beta7 build. Entity 7. OS Win x64.

I have a problem with attaching Sqlite to my app. I'm recieving *Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3' (System.DllNotFoundException)* or *IncorrectFormat (System.BadImageFormatException)* Errors. 
It seems that app can't find SQLite dll & lacks proper reference.

When switching between dnx versions, errors change (tried in both clr & coreclr). Errors - Former for x86, latter for x64. However, in both instances dnx & sqlite versions are matched.

My global.

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x64"
  }
}
```

My project.json partial.

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta7",
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta7",
  "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7",
  "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-",
  "EntityFramework.Sqlite": "7.0.0-beta7",
  "sqlite": "3.8.4.2"   (Nuget)
},
```

There is *sqlite3.dll* file in root but added reference just transforms into Nuget dependency 3.8.8.x within VS15.

Startup.cs partial.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlite()
            .AddDbContext<EF7oakContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration["SqliteString"])); }
```

... points to config.json.

```
"Data Source=<path>\\<DBname>.sqlite;"
```

I tried configuration within Context but if I understand correctly, that's just duplicating config.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
     optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=<path>\\<dbname>.sqlite;"); }
```

Simple custom Seed.cs.

```
public static void Seed(this IApplicationBuilder app) {
    var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<MyContext>();
    if (!context.People.Any()) {
        context.People.AddRange(
            new Sth { a = "a", b = "b" }
            (...) 
            );
            context.SaveChanges(); }
            (...)
    }
```

I checked [Stack-link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639087/getting-sqlite-to-work-in-asp-net-5-vnext) and [Stack-link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328490/why-am-i-getting-unable-to-load-dll-sqlite3-in-my-wpf-app), but solutions given there are not working.

Recap:

- Matched sqlite3 version added as app reference. Used *dnvm use [version]*
- Downloaded latest sqlite ([sqlite-link](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)) and put it in my app folder with unchanged name
- With each runtime - packages restored with *dnu restore*
- I want to match platform build options for sqlite, but there is no option in VS15, per @B. Clay Shannon similar problem from link no.1 above (earlier ASP v.)
- App works with local SQL Server DB.
- Migrations working.

I would appreciate any help or even loose suggestions.